# How to enter formula into ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

i have the following formula:

```
L = (l/22,1)^m
```

(l = Flow length)

m is calculated like this:

m = 0,5 when slope is >4 degrees

m = 1,2 * sin^1/3a  when slope is <4 degrees   (a = slope in degrees)

I already have the slope_deg and flow_length layer. Now I want to enter the formula to the raster calculator. I am new into ArcGIS and I dont know how i can implement it.

Comment: @Aaron I'd guess that @Max is from a country with a comma as the [radix point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator), so when he says `m = 0,5` he means `m = 1/2`.

Comment: @Aaron I think it means `L = (l/22.1)^m`

Answer (score 4):

You can incorporate `Con` into your raster algebra equation to make this calculation.  Alternatively, use the [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) tool.  The following links will help you build the `Con` expression:

[Conditional evaluation with Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000008000000)

[Building expressions in Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000)